# Can anyone tell me from which book is this chapter about the Bryant soliton?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

My advisor borrowed me these notes on the Bryant soliton and they seem to be part of some book on Ricci solitons. I've looked everywhere but couldn't find it (I only have these physical copies I took pictures of). I thought it could be a book from Ben Chow or Dan Knopf but I've gone through all their books I could find and didn't find this chapter there. It seems to be a really good book from what I've read so far, I'd really like to know what other contents it has.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6DI3.jpg

Comment: I guess you can just ask your advisor?

Comment: @ArcticChar he doesn't know either, someone else gave the notes to him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this is a terribly late answer, but I believe that note is an early draft of the book https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=GSM/235, Ricci Solitons in low dimensions, by Professor Chow, which is published last year (2023)